# Run grep or other commands on files on a web server

Tags: files, grep, http

I have files on another domain. What's the best way to use commands on them like grep?

```
wget http://path/to/file.txt | grep search
```

However this doesn't work. I guess I can use `curl` but is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `curl` to do this, in addition to `wget`.

```
$ curl -s <url> | grep <pattern>
```

#### Example

```
$ curl -s http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt | grep Colorama
965-7600 /Colorama        / CoCo / 300/1200 /General BBS
```

*Details of switches*

```
   -s, --silent
        Silent  or  quiet  mode.  Don't  show progress meter or error 
        messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask 
        for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what's the reasoning behind specifying an output file then supplying STDOUT when just plain `curl -s <url> | grep...` will do the same thing (afaik, just tested it)

Comment: @KevinDuke - no reason, I never tried it without `-o -` before 8-). It's likely that I interchange `wget` and `curl` so frequently that I've mixed the mandatory `-O -` of `wget` into the optional `curl -o -`.

Comment: @KevinDuke - I've edited that out of the A.

Comment: That's fine, thanks for the answer! Cheers :)

Comment: @KevinDuke - my pleasure, thanks for the Q!

Answer (score 2):

For a pipeline to work, the first command needs to write to **standard output**. `wget` doesn't normally do that, but there is a way to request it. From the wget(1) man page:

> -O file
>   --output-document=file
>      The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
>      will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
>      file, documents will be printed to standard output

So do it like this

```
wget -O - http://what/ever | grep something
```

You might find `wget`'s progress-reporting output to be annoyingly verbose in this context, in which case add the `-q` option to quiet it down.

```
wget -q -O - http://what/ever | grep something
```

Then you'll get nothing except the matching lines as output.